# Find Line that Contains String and Delete that Line in .txt file

Tags: c#, text

My goal is to erase the line that matches the String `DonatorPlayer`

```
if (targetPlayer == null)
{
    player.Message("That is not online. Please try again when they are online so that they may be notified in due time.");
}
else
{
    //switch (DonationCheck)
    //{
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            WhichLoopDelete += 1;
            if (line == DonatorPlayer)
            {
                switch (DonationCheck)
                {
                    case 0:
                        lines[WhichLoopDelete] = null;
                        File.Delete("Donators.txt");
                        File.Create("Donators.txt");

                        DonationCheck = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Donators.txt");
                        //Here is where I need to delete the line
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    //}
}
```

Comment: I honestly do not understand how to do it. I have googled it and even yahoo'ed it but cannot find an answer to what I need to do

Comment: Why is your switch statement that deletes "donators.txt" inside the while loop? How often will DonationCheck = 0? You haven't posted that code where DonationCheck and DonatorPlayer are declared; if you can post that, it might be easier to offer a solution that separates out deleting/creating file vs. deleting lines in an existing file and re-saving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use:

```
lines = lines.Where(line => !line.Equals("DonatorPlayer")).ToArray();
```

Comment: lines doesn't have a RemoveAll method

Comment: Add using system.Linq. which framework are you using?

Comment: Error 2 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAll' and no extension method 'RemoveAll' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\alex96\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GemsCraft\fCraft\Commands\DonatorCommands.cs 182 55 fCraft

Comment: did you add using system.Linq?

Comment: `RemoveAll` is not a LINQ method.  It's just a regular method of `List`.

Comment: the data is Array not List!

Comment: @Servy Regarding your edit, lines = lines.Where(line => !line.Equals("DonatorPlayer")).ToArray(); I get the error Error 1 A local variable named 'line' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'line', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else C:\Users\alex96\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GemsCraft\fCraft\Commands\DonatorCommands.cs 183 69 fCraft

Comment: @user2678408 I didn't change the code at all, I just formatted it properly so you can actually see what the author wrote.  That said, the error seems rather self explanatory.  You already have a `line` variable, and you cannot have another.  Just use a different variable name.